# image capture to localStorage not retrieving image consistently

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, local-storage

With help from this site (thanks [Musa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1353011/musa)!), I've managed to get some code that allows the user to capture an image and places that in local storage. I'm using the code in an iAd Producer widget embedded in an iBook.

Because I want to use the widget in a few locations in the book, I need to uniquely key each image stored. When I attempt this however, I run into problems which I can't explain.

Here's the code:

```
<div id="zeroDiv">
<input type="file" id="getPic" accept="image/*">
</div>
<div id="picWrapper">
<img id="image">
<div id="buttDiv">
    <button id="picButt"><span class="buttText">Insert image</span>

    </button>
</div>
</div>
```

and

```
uniqueID = "FC-p1"; //this will vary each time the code is used

$(document).ready(function () {
$("#getPic").on("change", gotPic);
if (localStorage['url' + uniqueID]){
    $("#image").attr("src", localStorage['url' + uniqueID]);
    $("#picButt span").text("Change image");
}    
});

function gotPic(event) {
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(){
    $("#image").attr("src", this.result);
    localStorage['url' + uniqueID] = this.result;
    $("#picButt span").text("Change image");
};
reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);   
}
```

here's a fiddle that works just fine on the web: https://jsfiddle.net/mikawaben/g02hcr95/2/

However, when I embed this into the ebook on the iPad I notice that when the page reloads I have strange behaviour. If an image is captured from the camera, this is replaced by the last image selected from the Camera Roll rather than the last image taken with the camera. I can't seem to find any consistency to this. Sometimes the image is replaced, sometimes the camera captured image remains.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried remote debugging w/ Safari to look at localStorage on the iPad?

Comment: @RaymondCamden - thanks for the reply. I've enabled the Develop menu and can see the iPad there. But it says No Inspectable Applications when I mouse over it. Any ideas on how to view it otherwise?

Comment: The app has to be actively running when you do it.

Comment: It was. I'm building a widget in iAd Producer to embed in an ebook via iBooks Author. Having the book open on the iPad doesn't change anything in the Develop menu in Safari. It still shows No Inspectable Applications even with the widget running in the page. I guess that as it's not a typical app, typical debugging methods won't apply. I think this might have to remain unanswered...

Comment: I totally missed the part about iAd. Sorry. Does XCode show anything in the debug output?

Comment: really appreciate you continuing to offer help with this. I have XCode but am unsure how I'd use it to debug something in iAd Producer / iBooks Author. Any ideas?

Comment: When you run the app, look in the debug output area in XCode.